# Is it possible to set the property of the condition dynamically?

Tags: c#

Normally when I want for example to find the first or default item of a List I use this way:

```
myList.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.MyPropery01 == "myCondition");
```

However, I would like to know if it is possible, for example by reflection, if I set the the property `MyProperty` dynamically, something like:

```
myList.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty01") == "myCondition");
```

Because sometimes I need to search for `MyProperty01`, sometimes for `MyProperty02`, `MyProperty03`, etc..

EDIT: in visual studio I get this error:

```
"Operator '==' can't be applied to operands of type System.reflection.PropertyInfo and string".
```

Comment: Yes, thats valid. Did you try it and run into a problem?

Comment: Can you pass an expression? Anyway the code seems to be valid and might work

Comment: Perhaps what you want is a dictionary, instead of a type with properties?

Comment: Yeah, or an indexer (who could do the reflection part for you ;))

Comment: I get an error in visual studio that says "Operator '==' can't be applied to operands of type System.reflection.PropertyInfo and string"

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía - That is because you must get the value out of the property info, please see me answer below for an example.

Comment: META: Aravol = Alvaro ? are you answering yourself ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can do that. You were pretty close, here is a demo you can drop in linqpad. Note that the important part is

`Single(l => l.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(l).ToString() == "Condition")`

```
void Main()
{
 var myList = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(i => new Xmas(i,"name"+i)).ToList();
 string prop = "name";
 Console.WriteLine(myList.Single(l => l.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(l).ToString() == "name6").name);
}

public class Xmas
{
 public int id { get; set; }
 public string name { get; set; }
 public Xmas( int id, string name )
 {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
 }
}
```

Comment: Nobody has yet showed you that you have to use the propertyInfo method SetValue to set it.

Comment: @john: what has that to do with the question?

Comment: @JohnPeters - Why would anyone use SetValue here? This is about getting a value while enumerating. The values of the list are already instantiated on the first line.

Comment: I assumed the title indicated they wanted to set a value. (Didn't read things to carefully)

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```
public class Apple
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public List<Apple> ApplesList {get;set;}

public void Process()
{
    PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Apple).GetProperty("Color");
    ApplesList = ApplesList.Where(r => (string)pi.GetValue(r) == "Red").ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also write an Extension method, that allow to get the property on every object, returning null when it doesn't exist, or doesn't have a GetMethod. You could keep a Cache if you want

```
public static class ObjectExtension
{
    static IDictionary<KeyValuePair<Type, string>, PropertyInfo> propertyCache = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<Type, string>, PropertyInfo>();

    public static object GetProperty(this object source, string propertyName, bool useCache = true)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var sourceType = source.GetType();
        KeyValuePair<Type, string> kvp = new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(sourceType, propertyName);
        PropertyInfo property = null;

        if (!useCache || !propertyCache.ContainsKey(kvp))
        {
            property = sourceType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            if (property == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var get = property.GetGetMethod();
            if (get == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (useCache)
            {
                propertyCache.Add(kvp, property);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            property = propertyCache[kvp];
        }
        return property.GetValue(source, null);
    }

    public static T GetProperty<T>(this object source, string propertyName)
    {
        object value = GetProperty((object)source, propertyName);
        if (value == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        return (T)value;
    }
}
```

A small test class could then be:

```
public class Item
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public string MyProperty3 { get; set; }

    public string MyProperty2 { protected get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
        MyProperty = "Test propery";
        MyProperty3 = "Test property 3";
        MyProperty2 = "Yoohoo";
    }
}
```

With a main class for testing

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Item item = new Item();
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            string key = "MyProperty" + (x > 0 ? x.ToString() : "");
            string value = item.GetProperty<string>(key);
            Console.WriteLine("Getting {0} = {1}", key, value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

which gives the expectable output of:

```
Getting MyProperty = Test propery
Getting MyProperty1 =
Getting MyProperty2 =
Getting MyProperty3 = Test property 3
```